# jobProgressToken: Jira (Zephyr) Rest API

Tags: rest, api, jira, jira-zephyr

I am using Jira (Zephyr) rest calls to create Test Cycle and add Tests cases into it. According to information mentioned **here**[1](http://docs.getzephyr.apiary.io/#reference/executionresource/add-tests-to-cycle/add-test's-to-cycle) if I use this rest call to add tests to Cycle then as a response I will get JobProgressToken. JobProgressToken is nothing but will tell the progress of Test Case addition in Test Cycle.

Now the problem which I am facing is I am not getting any output from this JobProgressToken. I tried firing the GET rest call using the format mentioned but I am getting empty response.

Can somebody please explain how to use this JobProgressToken to get the Progress of my task?
I want to verify that the tests which I added to Cycle are added susccessfully or not?

Answer (score 0):

Just ysterday I had the same issue. ZAPI documentation is really confusing. I found the following solution:

**GET** request for retrieving a job progress has the following form: http://jira/rest/zapi/latest/execution/jobProgress/0001498157843923-5056b64fdb-0001
where *0001498157843923-5056b64fdb-0001* is a value of the particular jobProgressToken

Right after getting a jobProgressToken as a result of some async operation, my code is waiting for the progress to became 1 (it is groing up from zero to 1)

```
    //get the job progress token as a result of some async operation invocation
    String jobProgressToken = new JSONObject(zapiResponse).getString("jobProgressToken");
    waitAsyncJobToBeCompleted(jobProgressToken);


void waitAsyncJobToBeCompleted(String jobProgressToken) {
    double jobProgress;
    do {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            LOG.error("Error while try to make the thread sleeping 500ms. " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        jobProgress = getJobProgress(jobProgressToken);
    } while (Double.compare(jobProgress, 1) <0);

private double getJobProgress(String jobProgressToken) {
    URI uri = makeUriFromString(String.format(
            GET_GetJobProgress, //Get request pattern
            connectionParameters.getJiraUrl(),//host
            jobProgressToken)); //parameters

    HttpResponse response = executeHttpRequestWithResponse(new HttpGet(uri));
    String zapiResponse = null;
    try {
        zapiResponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        LOG.trace("ZAPI RESPONSE: " + zapiResponse);
        EntityUtils.consumeQuietly(response.getEntity()); //cleanup the HTTP response
        double progress = new JSONObject(zapiResponse).getDouble("progress");
        LOG.debug("Job progress: " + progress);
        return progress;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        String err = String.format("Error while getting Zephyr API response: %s",
                e.getLocalizedMessage());
        LOG.fatal(err);
        throw new RestApiException(err, e);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        String err = String.format("Error while retrieving the job progress from JSON: %s\n%s",
                zapiResponse, e.getLocalizedMessage());
        LOG.fatal(err);
        throw new RestApiException(err, e);
    }

}
```

This is all magic :)

Following two logs: 1st for cloning test cycle, 2nd for deleting

```
ZephyrClient.invokeHttpPost     - URI=http://jira/rest/zapi/latest/cycle JSON payload={"projectId": "13795","clonedCycleId": 2643,"name": "ZAPI client test","description": "Created With ZAPI client unit test","versionId": "-1"}
ZephyrClient.cloneTestCycle     - RESPONSE JSON: {"jobProgressToken":"0001498218783350-5056b64fdb-0001"}
ZephyrClient.executeHttpRequestWithResponse     - HTTP REQUEST: GET http://jira/rest/zapi/latest/execution/jobProgress/0001498218783350-5056b64fdb-0001 HTTP/1.1
ZephyrClient.executeHttpRequestWithResponse     - HTTP RESPONSE: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
ZephyrClient.getJobProgress     - ZAPI RESPONSE: {"timeTaken":"0 min, 1 sec","stepMessage":"","summaryMessage":"","errorMessage":"","progress":0.56,"message":"","stepLabel":"","stepMessages":[]}
ZephyrClient.getJobProgress     - Job progress: 0.56
ZephyrClient.executeHttpRequestWithResponse     - HTTP REQUEST: GET http://jira/rest/zapi/latest/execution/jobProgress/0001498218783350-5056b64fdb-0001 HTTP/1.1
ZephyrClient.executeHttpRequestWithResponse     - HTTP RESPONSE: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
ZephyrClient.getJobProgress     - ZAPI RESPONSE: {"timeTaken":"0 min, 1 sec","stepMessage":"","summaryMessage":"","errorMessage":"","progress":0.98,"message":"","stepLabel":"","stepMessages":[]}
ZephyrClient.getJobProgress     - Job progress: 0.98
ZephyrClient.executeHttpRequestWithResponse     - HTTP REQUEST: GET http://jira/rest/zapi/latest/execution/jobProgress/0001498218783350-5056b64fdb-0001 HTTP/1.1
ZephyrClient.executeHttpRequestWithResponse     - HTTP RESPONSE: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
ZephyrClient.getJobProgress     - ZAPI RESPONSE: {"timeTaken":"0 min, 2 sec","stepMessage":"","summaryMessage":"","errorMessage":"","progress":0.98,"message":"","stepLabel":"","stepMessages":[]}
ZephyrClient.getJobProgress     - Job progress: 0.98
ZephyrClient.executeHttpRequestWithResponse     - HTTP REQUEST: GET http://jira/rest/zapi/latest/execution/jobProgress/0001498218783350-5056b64fdb-0001 HTTP/1.1
ZephyrClient.executeHttpRequestWithResponse     - HTTP RESPONSE: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
ZephyrClient.getJobProgress     - ZAPI RESPONSE: {"timeTaken":"0 min, 3 sec","stepMessage":"","summaryMessage":"","errorMessage":"","progress":1.0,"message":"Cycle ZAPI client test created successfully.","stepLabel":"","stepMessages":[]}
ZephyrClient.getJobProgress     - Job progress: 1.0
ZephyrClient.executeHttpRequestWithResponse     - HTTP REQUEST: GET http://jira/rest/zapi/latest/cycle?projectId=13795&versionId=-1 HTTP/1.1
ZephyrClient.executeHttpRequestWithResponse     - HTTP RESPONSE: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

---

```
ZephyrClient.invokeHttpDelete   - URI=http://jira/rest/zapi/latest/cycle/2727
ZephyrClient.deleteTestCycle    - RESPONSE JSON: {"jobProgressToken":"0001498218815183-5056b64fdb-0001"}
ZephyrClient.executeHttpRequestWithResponse     - HTTP REQUEST: GET http://jira/rest/zapi/latest/execution/jobProgress/0001498218815183-5056b64fdb-0001 HTTP/1.1
ZephyrClient.executeHttpRequestWithResponse     - HTTP RESPONSE: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
ZephyrClient.getJobProgress     - ZAPI RESPONSE: {"timeTaken":"0 min, 0 sec","stepMessage":"","summaryMessage":"","errorMessage":"","progress":1.0,"message":"{\"success\":\"Cycle ZAPI client test успешно удален\"}","stepLabel":"","stepMessages":[]}
ZephyrClient.getJobProgress     - Job progress: 1.0
ZephyrClient.executeHttpRequestWithResponse     - HTTP REQUEST: GET http://jira/rest/zapi/latest/cycle?projectId=13795&versionId=-1 HTTP/1.1
ZephyrClient.executeHttpRequestWithResponse     - HTTP RESPONSE: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

*P.S. This is not about how it should be done.
This is about how does it work for me ;)*